# Continously get user input

Tags: powershell

I have this piece in place after a user inputs an IP/machine name and ping it before running the rest of the code to make sure it is a valid IP/machine name.  If it is, it continues on to the rest of my code so no problem there.

The problem I'm having is getting it to sort of "restart" from the beginning of this when the IP is invalid.  I have it so it prompts the user to enter in a new machine name, but from there I can't get it to re-ping and attempt to verify again. As of right now it takes the new user input and just continues on with my code instead of re-running the ping sequence.

I suppose what I need is some sort of a loop to keep checking the user input if they enter an invalid IP until they do, but I just don't have the knowledge to figure that out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I feel like I'm so close!

```powershell
#-----Start Ping Target Machine-----#
Write-Host "Pinging Machine..." -Fore Yellow
$Ping = Test-Connection $machine -Quiet
if ($Ping -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Machine Found!" -Fore DarkGreen
}
else {
    if ($Ping -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "Machine Not Found - Check Name" -Fore Red
        $machine = Read-Host 'What is the machine name?'
    }
}
#-----End Ping Target Machine-----#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code inside an infinite loop and break when the ping is successful:

```powershell
while ($true)  # Loop continuously
{
    $machine = Read-Host 'What is the machine name?'
    Write-Host "Pinging Machine..." -Fore Yellow
    $Ping = Test-Connection $machine -Quiet
    if ($Ping)  # Check the ping (no need for '-eq $true')
    {
        Write-Host "Machine Found!" -Fore DarkGreen
        break;  # Break the loop since ping was successful
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Machine Not Found - Check Name" -Fore Red
    }
}
```